# On window re-size challenge using the Isotope masonry view

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my dilemma i have two views which work fine on toggle I have the Isotope and Masonry view, this works fine the challenge was to have the masonry view re size certain images depending on the view port, which I did using the below code.

```
$(function(){

  var $container = $('#container');
  // add randomize the size of images on the selected class//
  $container.find('.element').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        number = parseInt( $this.find('.number').text(), 10);           

    if (number  % 1 === 0 ){$this.addClass('width2');}

        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 599px)").matches) { 
            if ( number   % 5 === 3) {
                $this.addClass('height2');}
            }
        if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px) and (max-width:1023px)").matches) { 
            if ( number %12   % 5 === 2) {
                $this.addClass('height2');}
            }
        if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)").matches) { 
            if ( number %10   % 10 === 5)  {
                $this.addClass('height2');}                 
            }
    });
```

I make this work by assigning a number to an element using the below

```
var $l = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
        for(i=0; i < 40; i++){ $l[i].innerHTML = i + 1;}
```

what this does it ads a number to the class "number", I use the top code to return that number and I use modulus to assign a class to the returned numbers.

All of this works fine, if I open a browser window at the given size in my code the class is added to the assigned number range, now my issue is I have to make this work on window re-size which is where I am stuck, is there an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do or any tips will be greatly appreciated.

here is a bit of the HTML code

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element item audio hd phone">
        <p class="number"></p>
        <div class="element_holder bar">
            <div class="thumb">
                <div class="p-darkblue status opacity">
                    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> Available
                    <div class="modelfeatures">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span>
                        <span data-cat="hd" class="hd">HD</span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- hover over effect on masonary view -->
                <div class="overlay1">
                    <div class="p-darkblue col-lg-12 opacity">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>Available
                        <div class="modelfeatures">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></span>
                            <span class="hd">HD</span>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="model_name">kinkykat</div>
                        <div class="rating rating_margin">
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-star-half-full"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of overlay -->
                <img class="backdrop" src="image source" alt="Kikykat - Available">
                <div class="flame">
                    <div class="flame1"><i class="fa fa-fire"></i></div>
                    <div class="flame2"><i class="fa fa-firefox"></i></div>
                    <div class="flame3"><i class="fa fa-fire"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading a few doc's regarding isotop found the below solution

```
    // init Isotope
$(window).ready(function(){

    var $element_holder = $('.element_holder');
    $element_holder.hide();
    var $container = $( '.element' );

           $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $element_holder.fadeIn();

                $container.isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.element_holder',
                    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                    fitRows: {
                            gutter: 1,
            columnwidth: '.element_holder',
                        }
         });
});
```

the issue was the gutter which was not set. :('